# Errors after importing new Libraries in IntelliJ

Tags: java, oracle, nullpointerexception, weblogic, osb

I added my libraries and I get these errors while clicking "run with JRebel"

my new libraries are:

```
oracle.servicebus.configfwk.jar
oracle.servicebus.kernel-api.jar
oracle.servicebus.kernel-wls.jar


<Feb 23, 2015 1:27:37 PM EET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsc.v11.endpoint.RegistrationRequesterPortImpl" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myapp-web-dev-2.0".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.SchemaGenerator.addSchemaComponents(SchemaGenerator.java:297)
Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And also have no duplicate weblogic.jar
[image: screenshot]

[**Here is the entire error log**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10371064/)

Comment: So, did you check the server log? It says you have a nullpointer exception. Did you check the stacktrace to see if there 's some inject, autowired, initialization, ... you missed?

Comment: Most likely you have a compatibility issue in the versions of the library you are using. Have you asked your support what they suggest? e.g. weblogic.

Comment: @Stultuske here is my weblogic server log http://paste.ubuntu.com/10371107/ still cant figure out whats wrong with it. i will check weblogic version now. but it was working 2 days ago, before the libs included.

Comment: Please don't paste your log on another site. Edit your question and add the log here